# Update + st_within

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want update table A.localidad, using st_within table B.licalidad

I need make centroid from table a for more precision.

The error, is the subquery return more one row

```
update test.test set 
localidad = (select st_within (st_centroid(a.geom), b.geom) from test.test a, capas_gral.localidades_amba b)
```

> ERROR:  una subconsulta utilizada como expresión retornó más de un registro
>   (translation via Google: a subquery used as an expression returned more than one record)

Comment: This has already been answered recently, and the answer is pure SQL, making this marginally off-topic. You do have a potential problem in that `ST_Centroid` can generate points outside the feature, and an inefficiency in that you didn't add an `a.geom && b.geom and ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

Updates column ***localidad*** of table **test.test** to take value of table **capas_gral.localidades_amba** where the centroid of **test.test** is completely inside **capas_gral.localidades_amba**.

```
UPDATE test.test
SET localidad = b.localidad 
FROM capas_gral.localidades_amba b
WHERE ST_WITHIN(st_centroid(test.test.geom), b.geom)
```